# Load images from computer PHP / HTML

Tags: php, html, image, web

at this moment i am in China. I created a simple website for uploading some pictures to share with friends. Adding comments etcetera. I upload all the pictures but they load very slow in China so my idea was:

When i am logged in (can find in session) i will simply load the pictures from my local machine and not from the website because it is very slow or it doesnt even load the pictures.

I tried this:

```
        if ($_SESSION['id'] == 1) {  //check if i am logged in
            $china = "file:///F:/";
        } else { $china = ''; }
```

after that:

```
        echo "<div id='title" . $image['id'] . "'><h2>" . $image['title'] . "</h2></div>
                        <img src='$china" . $image['url'] . "'/>";
```

But when i open my browser it seems it can find the picture because it has a width but no height so the picture isnt shown. When i follow the link to the picture with the devoloper tools it will show the picture so the links are right.

I think this is not working because of some security reasons or something. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: how you store those picture in your client machine?

Comment: On my F disk in the folder like i it shows. Browsing to file:///F:/done/20130221215605.jpg is no problem at all but i want them to be shown in my page :)

Comment: Why are you doing that? Try change permission of your F drive , to allow read

Comment: As i said, i have allready permission to my drive. When i browse in my browser directly to the file there is no problem. Only when it is placed in HTML it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all it was very easy to do, i ran a local webserver on my computer (apache). Didnt think about that but pretty straight forward.

Thanks for thinking with me.